# Find swapped values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, difference

Let's say, that there are given 2 arrays that contain both same values and it is known that only 2 values can be swapped at once.

```
originalArray = [ "i0w66c25", "vnc1ar7f", "ajo3u8xl", "i13kn0bs" ]
sortedArray =   [ "vnc1ar7f", "i0w66c25", "ajo3u8xl", "i13kn0bs" ]
```

The first array is the original one, latter sorted version.

As you can see, the first two values have been swapped in the latter version.

How can you detect and return what values have been changed like for example this: (or if you have any better idea, go ahead!)

```
[
 {
   "changedWhat": "vnc1ar7f",
   "oldPosition": 1,
   "newPosition": 0
 }
 {
    "changedWhat": "i0w66c25",
    "oldPosition": 0,
    "newPosition": 1
 }
]
```

Comment: I looped through original list and newer list and got "uncaught exception: out of memory" error in browser... but I can get what has changed but how can I get the new and older position?

Comment: Please post the code you tried in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming both arrays are of the same length, contain no duplicate values, and have the same items

```js
var originalArray = ["i0w66c25", "vnc1ar7f", "ajo3u8xl", "i13kn0bs"];
var sortedArray = ["vnc1ar7f", "i0w66c25", "ajo3u8xl", "i13kn0bs"];

var changedItems =
  originalArray

    .filter(function(item, index) {
      return item != sortedArray[index]
    })

    .map(function(item) {
      return {
        "changedWhat": item,
        "oldPosition": originalArray.indexOf(item),
        "newPosition": sortedArray.indexOf(item)
      };
    });

console.log(changedItems);
```

First, we use [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to determine which items exactly are out of place.

Then, we [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) those items to an array of custom objects.

Comment: Thanks, this is very cleaver solution. Can you tell me why
`"oldPosition": +index`. Why + before index?

Comment: + sign forces conversion to number

Comment: Thanks! I just looked it up as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus
Everyday learning new things. :o

Comment: @GenertOrginaal, we all do ;-)

Comment: @AmmarCSE looks really clean, though I would prefer your older version as .indexOf(item) makes it a bit more inefficient ;). Could replace with item != sortedArray[index] if you know they are the same lenght

Comment: @AmmarCSE after reading your code better, it doesn´t really work well because when you filter you are loosing the original indexes: http://jsfiddle.net/qptw6mpf/

Comment: @juvian, right again! Updated my answer. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @GenertOrginaal, please take a look at my updated answer. Juvian pointed out a flaw in my original answer which I have fixed

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note: this will only work if there are no duplicated values in the array

```
originalArray = [ "i0w66c25", "vnc1ar7f", "ajo3u8xl", "i13kn0bs" ]
sortedArray =   [ "vnc1ar7f", "i0w66c25", "ajo3u8xl", "i13kn0bs" ]


var original = {}
var changes = []
originalArray.forEach(function(val,pos){original[val] = pos}) // we store original array indices of the values

sortedArray.forEach(function(val,pos){
    if(original[val] != pos){ // if position changed
        changes.push({changed:val, oldPos:original[val],newPos:pos})
    }
})

console.log(changes)
```

Comment: Your's solution works and is nice but @AmmarCSE solution is cleaner so to speak.

Comment: @GenertOrginaal Yeah I agree :)